# Detect ios Google app

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, browser, browser-detection

I have an issue with FB login flow in Google app.
Currently for some mobile browsers I follow redirect auth flow.

Like this: `var w = window.open("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?....", "_blank", ...)`.

But `w` variable is `undefined` in iOS in [Google app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-app-search-made-just/id284815942?mt=8)
So I just want to use another strategy for this case. 
Can you help me please with how to detect this browser? (using `userAgent` or something)

Or maybe someone can help with the best fb auth strategy for this case

Comment: I’d recommend to just let the redirect flow work in the current window, instead of trying to open a new one ... the latter causes all kinds of problems on mobile.

Comment: @CBroe, at first I just wanted to save the current working flow for mobile browsers except Google Search app. But finally followed your suggestion and made auth strategy without redirects, but in the current tab with the app. Thanks

Comment: @DanilGudz how did you find out that the variable was not defined ?